# GPU memory access and usage (CUDA)

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm new to CUDA and quite confused about the memory types and how to use them right.

What I want to do is pretty simple. I have a two-dimensional array `data` of NxN elements where N is 4096.

Let `i,j` be the current element. I need to access all its neighbors:
`(i + m, j + n)` with `m` and `n` being any of `[-1, 0, 1]`.
For `i = 0`, `i-1` becomes `N-1`. The same for `j = 0` (periodic boundary conditions).

1. I do some calculations using these neighbors:

   ```
   data[i][j] = data[i][j] + a * data[i+1][j] + b * data[i+1][j+1] + ...
   ```

2. Then I need to wait until all other `N * N - 1` threads do these calculations and synchronize the `data` array.
3. I iterate it `k` times.

**I'm unsure if I should iterate within my kernel or outside as I don't know how it affects the memory.**

The way I understand it, my kernel should look like this:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(float* data, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y) % rows; 
    int j = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) % cols; 
    
    i = (i >= 0) ? i : rows + i;
    j = (j >= 0) ? j : cols + j;

    int t = i * sizeof(float) + j;
    
    for(int m = -1; m <= 1; m ++) 
    {
        for(int n = -1; n <= 1; n ++) 
        {
            if(m != 0 || n != 0) 
            {
                int s = (i + m) * sizeof(float) + (j + n);
                data[t] += data[s]/2;  // just an example 
            }
        }
    }   
}
    
...

int k = 1000;
int rows = 4096;
int cols = 4096;

dim3 block(8,8);
dim3 grid ( (cols + block.x -1)/block.x, (rows + block.y -1)/block.y );

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    my_kernel<<<grid, block>>>(reinterpret_cast<float*>(mat.data), rows, cols );
}
```

What I don't understand is how the memory works here.
Does that mean the `data` array stays in global memory and is accessed from the kernel in every thread? As far as I understand it, it's relatively slow I need it compute as fast as possible.

At the same time shared memory is limited to 48KB per block and the `data` array wouldn't fit because its size is 64mb (4*4096*4096 bytes). Besides it would limit computations to a single block.

Still, I don't actually need the whole `data` array in every thread. I only need 9 elements. My gut feeling says it should work without accessing global memory. Is that possible? Does it make sense? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to implement what you want using shared memory, and yes, it should accelerate your code since your problem is memory-bound.

Two years ago I successfully implemented something like this. In order to figure out the details, I looked at the matrix multiplication example (where shared memory was used). It can be found in CUDA Samples folder.

Note, that in your case the major difference is that your adjacent blocks should overlap (by 1 row or 1 column) (you will require it when you will be calculating your result at each of the block's boundaries). The implementation is straight-forward and can be done **in 1 kernel call**, where you:

1) Fill up a shared-memory array.

2) `__syncthreads();`

3) Perform necessary calculation using a shared-memory array.

Choose the `block_size` so that the shared array can be fit in the shared memory of each block. The grid size will be the ratio of your original array and block_size

Answer (score 0):

There is an official sample for this so-called stencil pattern in 3D using shared memory: [`5_Domain_Specific/FDTD3d`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/5_Domain_Specific/FDTD3d/inc/FDTD3dGPUKernel.cuh). As the third dimension is computed sequentially, it should be easy to cut this down to 2D. So yes, even with the outer `k` loop putting a tile + "halo" layer into shared memory is a good idea, as even during a single `k` iteration multiple threads will access the same coordinate `i, j`. Although one has to benchmark carefully with caching becoming more and more powerful on GPUs. I have already seen 3D stencil codes that did not benefit from shared memory due to good L1 caching of the hardware.

Generally one needs grid-wide synchronization between `k` iterations. This is often achieved using one kernel launch per iteration (See the sample).

With today's [grid sync feature](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization) from the cooperative groups API, it is possible to do the iteration inside the kernel, but this will be harder to implement due to the hardware-limited amount of blocks for cooperative launches. This means that each block might need to compute multiple tiles (or tiles too big for shared memory) sequentially similar to the 3D loop which would undermine the purpose of doing the computation in a single launch as data would not be kept in shared memory. Also there is no guarantee that this will actually be faster than using multiple launches.

There are some algorithmic strategies for minimizing the amount of synchronization/communication between blocks. They are often applied in multi-node HPC codes utilizing MPI (here: MPI nodes <-> CUDA blocks). For example one can do redundant computations by overlapping the tiles (creating duplicate layers which are not the same as outer "ghost" or "halo" layers) and then shrinking the effective tile size with each "inner iteration" (blocking the `k` iterations). This way one might achieve multiple but not all `k` iterations in a single kernel launch without a cooperative launch. One issue for this optimization on the GPU is that the amount parallelism inside the block goes down with the inner iterations.